# Two mountpoints created in /media for one partition

Tags: mount

I have a partition on my Ubuntu installation that is named 'Media' at the second position. It comes in as /dev/sda2. Now when it mounts, starting I think with Ubuntu 10.10, I get TWO directories in /media when it mounts:

/media/Media (owned by root, nothing in it)
/media/Media_ (owned by my normal user with all the contents in it)
This is not the way that I remember it happening before Ubuntu 10.10.

Other drives, external via USB, only have one directory made in /media.

In all cases, (all) the directory(ies) is (are) removed by GTK/Nautilus, et.al. when unmounted.

Is this normal? Is it a bug I should report? I'm working on a backup script, and I want to know the correcty behavior. Mabye this is something to do with the fact that it's a non root(filesystem) but an internal drive?

Comment: Hmmmmm, I could have SWORN I looked there first, but now I see that there was already a directory called '/dev/Mount' and that instead of mounting to that, Ubuntu created '/dev/Media_', but still called it Media in Nautilus. As I recall, that is non standard behaviour. 'mount' would have just mounted over it and the previous contents would disappear until the drive was 'umount'ed. Now I have to redo all my libraries that I had for my media players.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus automount to `/media/$label`, when partition has a label and `/media/$label` do not exist. If it exsists, Nautilus choose the alternative `/media/$label_` . Then the mount point is removed when you unmount.

The fact that you have both is due probably to a `/media/$label` not removed for some reasons. Solution:

- unmount the partition
- remove the path `/media/$label`

Now when you mount the partition again, the correct path should be used.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked great. Didn't know about the Ubuntu behavior. It's not the standard 'mount' behavior, but the Ubuntu/Nautilus behavior.

Comment: @Dennis: it works? If so, it would be nice if you at least upvote me.

Comment: Well, I checked before I ever saw your answer, sorry. It never occurred to me to upvote anyway. :-( I'm sitll learning the ropes on this awesome site. Consider yourself now upvoted.

Comment: The other wierd thing is that I have a 21 reputation on stack overflow, but only got 1 when my question was transferred to here. So I can't upvote you. Sorry.